# Unity GameObject doesn't run smooth when moved a second time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, gameobject, lerp

So I have a script to move gameobjects around. When I move a gameObject one time it's smooth. But when I move it a second time the movement very slow and looks abit buggy.

The first input in the movement script is the object, then the position it needs to move to and the speed as last parameter. All coordinates are based on the localposition. I use wait because I want to wait before executing the second movement.

I tried to move other objects twice as well but they all end up moving very slow/buggy.

I do not want to run this in Update that's why I use coroutine.

Here's my code:

```
IEnumerator MovementGentryOne()
{
    StartCoroutine(Movement(GentryOne, MovementCoords.GentryOneBasin, gentryspeed));
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    StartCoroutine(Movement(GentryOneArm, MovementCoords.GentryArmMoved, gentryspeed));
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    StartCoroutine(Movement(GentryOnePicker, MovementCoords.GentryPickerPick, gentryspeed));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
//this one is not working smooth.
    StartCoroutine(Movement(GentryOnePicker, MovementCoords.GentryPickerStart, gentryspeed)); 
    yield return null;
}

private IEnumerator Movement(GameObject toMove, Vector3 position, float time)
{

    float elapsedTime = 0;
    while (elapsedTime < time)
    {
        toMove.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(toMove.transform.localPosition, position, (elapsedTime / time));
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    toMove.transform.localPosition = position;
}
```

Anyone an idea what is going wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you confirm that one Movement-Coroutine has finished before you're starting a new one? Otherwise you'd be fighting over movement, which would cause weird, unsmooth and laggy movement.

Comment: Can you use yield return StartCoroutine instead of waiting seconds in between?

Comment: It seems the coroutine doesn't stop. With the debugger I noticed it never reaches the statement after yield return null

Comment: The biggest question is: **How** and **where** are you calling MovementGentryOne from? Are GentryOne, GentryOneArm and GentryOnePicker child of each other?

Comment: I solved the problem in the answer below. And yes they are all children of each other. The method is called from the start method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer the method never breaks out of the while loop. So I edited the while statement to:
toMove.transform.localPosition != position

Comment: Hi, Don't compare `Vector3`. I am too lazy to explain why but your original code with the while loop is the appropriate way to do it. It just needs a little-bit of modification.